# React: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I faced this error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I've checked all the previous questions related to similar errors but can't find out what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import classes from './BuildControls.css'
import BuildControl from './BuildControl/BuildControl.css'

const controls = [
    {label: 'Salad',type: 'salad'},
    {label: 'Bacon',type: 'bacon'},
    {label: 'Cheese',type: 'cheese'},
    {label: 'Meat',type: 'meat'},
];

const buildControls = (props) => (
    <div className={classes.buildControls}>
        {controls.map(ctrl => (
            <BuildControl 
                key={ctrl.label} 
                label={ctrl.label}
                added={() => props.ingredientAdded(ctrl.type)}
                 />
        ))}       
    </div>
);

export default buildControls;
```

this is the file which contains error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing the BuildControl *stylesheet* as `BuildControl` and trying to use that to create the BuildControl element. You need to instead `import BuildControl from './BuildControl/BuildControl.jsx'` (assuming that's your component's filename and location).

To render a child component inside a parent component, you need to import the child component's JS file.

As a side note, it's common practice to always use [pascal case](http://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase) (e.g., "BuildControls") when naming components.

Comment: Man! That was really a silly mistake.... I didn't paid attention to those import statements. I just focused on the lines below. Thanks mate!